# How to add records to a table in flask_sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask to make a project, I choose Flask-sqlalchemy to store data. Database is stored locally:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///manage.db'
```

I define two class:

```
class House(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'house'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    block: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String, nullable=False)
    number: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String, nullable=False)
    area: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer) 

class Residents(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'residents'
    r_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String, primary_key=True) 
    r_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db`your text`.String) 
    r_phone: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String, nullable=False)
    r_work_place: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

And I define a table that records residents and their houses:

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
db.Column('house_id',db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('house.id')),
db.Column('res_id',db.String, db.ForeignKey('residents.r_id'))
)
```

Now I want to add records to table 'tags' which is defined as db.Table, how to achieve this process?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a mapping for your bi-directional many-to-many relationship as described in [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#setting-bi-directional-many-to-many), you can add and remove your objects as in a list.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    Mapped, 
    relationship
)
from typing import List

class House(db.Model):
    # ...

    residents: Mapped[List['Residents']] = relationship(
        secondary=tags, back_populates='houses'
    )

class Residents(db.Model):
    # ...

    houses: Mapped[List['House']] = relationship(
        secondary=tags, back_populates='residents'
    )
```

```py
house = House(...)
db.session.add(house)
db.session.commit()

resident = Residents(...)
house.residents.append(resident)
db.session.commit()
```